# Is it okay to use a singleton as "universal memory"?

Tags: oop, object, singleton

I'm using a `Singleton` object as a way of storing some data. I like using it out of convenience because now any of my view controllers can access the data.

Otherwise, I would have each view controller passing on the data to the next view controller, which seems a bit tedious.

I understand this may go against some professional programming principles.

Is this a terrible idea?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, it is a terrible idea.

On one side, you are creating a memory leak since the Singleton will never be garbage collected and therefore never be freed even when it isnt needed.

Additionally, the Singleton makes your software impossible to test since you cant mock them or use temporary data in any way.

If you have problem passing with passing data around, I'd take a look at Dependency Injection. This is quite an advanced topic for an oop beginner tough...